# Create a layer that add a zero-channel to my tensor

Tags: python, image, keras, layer

I am working on DCSCN (a neural network for image super-rez) and I want to evaluate uncertainty according to Alex Kendall and Yarin Gal method in "What Uncertainties Do We Need in Bayesian Deep Learning for Computer Vision?" using Keras.

For this, I need a layer that take a tensor of shape (?,n,m,3) and return a tensor of (?,n,m,4) with (?,n,m,-1) with zeros.

I tried this function :

```
def AddChan(**kwargs):

    def layer(x):
        input_shape = K.int_shape(x)
        output_shape = (input_shape[0], input_shape[1],input_shape[2],1)
        z = K.zeros(output_shape)
        res = K.concatenate([x, z], axis=-1)
        return res
    return Lambda(layer, **kwargs)
```

which raise :

```
Expected int32, got None of type '_Message' instead.
```

I think that's because `input_shape[0]` is dynamic but i don't see another way to get what I want.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `K.int_shape` with `K.shape` to get the symbolic shape of a tensor or variable rather than an integer shape.